# SublimeText: “Highlights other occurrences of the currently selected text” doesn’t work correctly after change the “word_separators”

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

In Sublime Text, I recently change the "word_separators" in User Settings, removing the '$' for when I select a variable it select the '$' character too.

This works fine, but when I select a variable with '$' the other same variables doesn't Highlights. (with the normal text works fine)

**Any idea how can I fix this ¿?**

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue with `sublime text` existed from a long time now but fortunately,
there's a `package` called `WordHighlight` which you can install to solve this issue quite easily,
just visit the below link

https://github.com/SublimeText/WordHighlight

you will get installation information from above link, after installation you may need to restart your `sublime text`.

That's it!